# Salesforce Field Values Uniqueness

Tags: validation, page-layout, validation-rule, fields, page-validation

I have created a field which has to be unique so i have checked the unique checkbox while creating the field

Its working well but the problem is that the page is redirecting to another blank page and I’m getting the following error

> The Proposed Dara changes would violate uniqueness constraint

But i want it on the same page as error similar to a validation rule saying

> Error: Duplicate value on record: Test Account

And Test Account should be a hyperlink to the record which has the value Test Account in that field

Comment: Is that a new field or you are trying to make an existing field as unique?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal It’s a new field in a new object

Comment: are  you facing problem while creating records or while creating fields?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal it’s while creating records

Comment: That looks like the default behavior in classic (in LEX, it does show you the error on the screen but with limited ,message). Unless you override the behavior, don't think the message as expected will be shown. With the use case that you have of showing the duplicate records, you may like to consider Duplicate Management instead.